# How to pass variable in Ansbile?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Could not find out why variables not being picked up in Ansible 2.3.1.0.

File structure:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── test1.yml
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── test1
├── roles
│   └── install
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
├── testing.retry
└── testing.yml
```

`group_vars/test1.yml`:

```
---
test_var: "This is from host_vars file"
```

`content of host_vars/test1`:

```
---
test_var: "This is from host_vars file"
```

Content of `roles/install/tasks/main.yml`:

```
---

- name: Debug
  debug: var=test_var
```

Result is:

```
 ansible-playbook -i hosts testing.yml 

PLAY [This is testing] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [install : Debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test_var": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Expect output:

```
test_var = This is from host_vars file
```

Comment: The answer might be similar. but the title was not really clear. Thanks though! How to pass variable in Ansbile? is much better!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ansible is not reading `group_vars/test1.yml` because you don't have a group named `test1`.

   If you wan't to define group_vars for any group, you should name it `all`, so the file should be `group_vars/all.yml`.
2. Ansible is not reading `host_vars/test1` because you don't have a host named `test1`.

   If you wan't to define host_vars for your localhost, you should name it `localhost`, so the file should be `host_vars/localhost.yml`.